# Coletar nome do arquivo utilizado

Tags: python-3.x

Estou concluindo um código que utiliza muito a função **copy** de **shutil**. Como vou distribuir o arquivo em formato executável depois e provavelmente em algum momento vão mudar o nome dele, quero saber se tem como eu coletar o nome do arquivo onde o script está sendo rodado.
Algo como:

```
nome = os.getbasename()
print(nome)
-globancy.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem diversas opções na verdade. Dessas apresento-lhe três:

```
import os    
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

```
import sys
print (sys.argv[0])]
```

```
print (__file__)
```

***Existe uma [discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152963/get-the-name-of-current-script-with-python) interessante no SO a respeito dos prós e contras do uso de cada uma. Vale a pena consultar.***

Onde:

- `__file__` é o arquivo atualmente em execução, conforme detalhado na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-43):

> `__file__` é o nome do caminho do arquivo a partir do qual o módulo foi carregado, se foi carregado de um arquivo. O `__file__`atributo pode
>   estar faltando para certos tipos de módulos, como módulos C que estão
>   vinculados estaticamente ao interpretador; para módulos de extensão
>   carregados dinamicamente a partir de uma biblioteca compartilhada, é o
>   nome do caminho do arquivo de biblioteca compartilhada.

- `sys.argv[0]`(requer importação `sys)` é o nome do script que foi chamado
     a partir da linha de comando e pode ser um caminho absoluto, conforme
     detalhado na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> `argv[0]` é o nome do script (depende do sistema operacional se esse é um
>   nome de caminho completo ou não). Se o comando foi executado usando a
>   opção `-c` de linha de comando para o intérprete, `argv[0]` será definido para a string '`-c`'. Se nenhum nome de script foi passado para o
>   interpretador Python, `argv[0]` é a string vazia.

As informações que compõe essa resposta foram [retiradas daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514032/9305064). Agradeço ao usuário [Yoel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903832/yoel).

Answer (score 0):

Interpretando sua pergunta como “Descobrindo o nome do script corrente em Python”.

Assim, seguem algumas soluções conforme [questão em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152963/get-the-name-of-current-script-with-python):

> O atributo **__file__** em qualquer arquivo te dará o caminho para este.
>   Então se quiser omitir o restante do caminho, use **os.path.basename(__file__)**.<sup>[2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-43)</sup> <sup>[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)</sup>
>
> Neste ínterim, você pode ainda importar **__main__** e utilizar o mesmo atributo **__file__**.<sup>[4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__)</sup>
>
> Ou ainda **sys.argv[0]**, mas lembre-se de igualmente utilizar **os.path.basename** caso queira apenas o nome do arquivo.<sup>[5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)</sup>

*os e sys são módulos e devem ser importados para serem utilizados.*